# Slack API chat.postMessage URL Unfurling

Tags: slack-api

I have a bot app that sends a message to the slack channel.  I am using https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/ to send messages to the slack channel.

My message sometimes has few links (GIF) which are being rendered in the channel as a plain link.

I want them to be unfurled so that it can display animated GIF on the channel itself.

I tried passing unfurl_links: true to the API parameter however it doesn't work.

Here is my JSON payload

```
{
    "text": "Anniversary Alert :confetti_ball:",
    "channel": "C01AGGP63ST",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Anniversary Alert :confetti_ball:\n\nLet's all take a moment to congratulate <@U024FCGPW> on their 10 year anniversary!\n\nWe wish you a very happy anniversary and many more great years ahead with us.\n\nhttps://media0.giphy.com/media/1yjpDZgvGkb6nTynq3/giphy.gif?cid=cbd9d2f95475c686b1a293a6cf43de5f3f640e4eb012f714&rid=giphy.gif"
            }
        }
    ],
    unfurl_links: true
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Used "attachments" property of the API payload and it unfurls the link

```
{
    "text": "Anniversary Alert :confetti_ball:",
    "channel": "C01AGGP63ST",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Anniversary Alert :confetti_ball:\n\nLet's all take a moment to congratulate <@U024FCGPW> on their 10 year anniversary!\n\nWe wish you a very happy anniversary and many more great years ahead with us.\n\nhttps://media0.giphy.com/media/1yjpDZgvGkb6nTynq3/giphy.gif?cid=cbd9d2f95475c686b1a293a6cf43de5f3f640e4eb012f714&rid=giphy.gif"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
     {
        "text": "",
        "image_url": "https://media0.giphy.com/media/1yjpDZgvGkb6nTynq3/giphy.gif?cid=cbd9d2f95475c686b1a293a6cf43de5f3f640e4eb012f714&rid=giphy.gif"
     }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The big gotcha here is that slack unfurl is only triggered when it's a user (bots do not trigger unfurls). Too bad - I'm running into the same issue - unfurl was going to be the way to go but I missed the fine print. I think I'm going to just go with a chat threaded reply (which is way less pretty).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).